# URL rewrite with htaccess gets 404 error - AngularJS html5 mode

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, apache, .htaccess

### Angular js page refresh 404 error after removing # and ! from URL

I working on an angular(1.7.5) project, in which I want to remove # and ! from the URL, for that, I use the below code

```
myApp.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

and added base tag in index.html in the root folder

```
<base href="/myApp/">
```

and .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

finally, I removed the # and ! from the URL, but the issue is when I refresh the page or open the same URL in new tab the page get 404 error,

```
http://localhost/dev/ ----- works fine
```

but

```
http://localhost/dev/login ----404 error
```

I dont know how to resolve the issue help me thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the `.htaccess` rules like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `.htaccess`. The problem is that your current rules only forward the first path in the URL. Instead, you need to have it forward *all* nested paths.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```